# Copy specific data from one object to another object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two (**RecorderConfigModel and RecorderFinalModel**) objects with the following models

```
export interface RegexPair {
  regex_id?: number;
  regex_name?: string;
}

export interface FinalRegexPair {
  regex_id?: any;
}

export class RecorderConfigModel {
    blockmode_id: number;
    blockmode_name: string;
    datapacking_id: number;
    datapacking_type: string;
    miniframe_id: number;
    miniframe_name: string;
    name: string;
    recorder_id: number;
    recorderformat_id: number;
    recorderformat_name: string;
    recordertype_id: number;
    recordertype_type: string;
    regexes: RegexPair[];
    subframesize_id: number;
    subframesize_name: string;
  }



 export class RecorderFinalModel {
    recordertype_id: number;
    datapacking_id: number;
    miniframe_id: number; 
    subframesize_id: number; 
    blockmode_id: number; 
    recorderformat_id: number; 
    name: string;
    regex?: FinalRegexPair[];
  }
```

I want to copy specific data from **RecorderConfigModel** to **RecorderFinalModel** (for example: *recordertype_id*, *miniframe_id* i.e mostly the ID's).

Below is the code through which I am trying to copy but I cannot get it to work as I get this error (*cannot set property of undefined*).
Now I am unable to understand what wrong am I doing with the code.

```
this.finalRecorderConfigModel.recordertype_id = this.recorderConfigModel.recordertype_id;
this.finalRecorderConfigModel.datapacking_id = this.recorderConfigModel.datapacking_id;
this.finalRecorderConfigModel.miniframe_id = this.recorderConfigModel.miniframe_id;
this.finalRecorderConfigModel.subframesize_id = this.recorderConfigModel.subframesize_id;
this.finalRecorderConfigModel.blockmode_id = this.recorderConfigModel.blockmode_id;
this.finalRecorderConfigModel.recorderformat_id = this.recorderConfigModel.recorderformat_id;
this.finalRecorderConfigModel.name = this.recorderConfigModel.name;
this.recorderConfigModel.regexes.forEach(element => {
  this.finalRecorderConfigModel.regex.push({regex_id: element.regex_id});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not have defined your `finalRecorderConfigModel` in your component.So you can do something like

```
finalRecorderConfigModel:RecorderFinalModel ={regex:[]};
```

or before starting the assignment of properties

```
this.finalRecorderConfigModel={regex:[]};
this.finalRecorderConfigModel.recordertype_id = this.recorderConfigModel.recordertype_id;
....
```

for other props either set to null or make them nullable in your model same like `regex?: FinalRegexPair[];`

Comment: I have defined them in the component at the start
 recorderConfigModel: RecorderConfigModel;
  finalRecorderConfigModel: RecorderFinalModel;

Comment: @OnkarNirhali `recorderConfigModel: RecorderConfigModel` is declaration not definition. `recorderConfigModel: RecorderConfigModel={}` is definition please do some research over google for the same